# Build com problemas

Tags: android, build

Segue as configurações do projeto:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}



apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mobile"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    maven {
        url "http://mylibs:8081/nexus/content/repositories/releases/"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.6.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okio:okio:1.6.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:percent:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:2.4.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.3.0'
    compile ('com.library:okhttpmodel:0.0.1'){force =true}
}
```

**Manifset**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.mobile" >

    <!-- To access Google+ APIs: -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" /> <!-- To retrieve the account name (email) as part of sign-in: -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" /> <!-- To auto-complete the email text field in the login form with the user's emails -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <!--uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" /-->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION" />
    <!--action android:name="android.location.PROVIDERS_CHANGED" /-->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.mobile.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <application
        android:name="com.mobile.UIApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <receiver
            android:name="com.mobile.services.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <category android:name=“com.mobile.application.AutoApplication" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <service android:name="com.mobile.services.NotificationService" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.mobile.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.mobile.LaunchActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.mobile.LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/login_label_title"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:noHistory="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustPan" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <!-- <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" /> -->
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.mobile.SignUpActivity"
            android:label="@string/sign_up_label_title"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustPan" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.mobile.TripActivity"
            android:label="@string/new_trip_action"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" >
        </activity>

        <service
            android:name=“com.mobile.receivers.ActivityReceiver"
            android:exported="false" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value=“XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.mobile.CalibrateActivity"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance"
            android:noHistory="true"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.UserDialog" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=“com.mobile.ForgotPasswordActivity"
            android:excludeFromRecents="false"
            android:label="@string/title_forgot_password"
            android:noHistory="false"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustResize" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=“com.mobile.LastTripMapActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_last_trip_map" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ChangePasswordActivity"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance"
            android:noHistory="true"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.UserDialog" >
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name=“com.mobile.receivers.PhoneCallReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:name=“com.mobile.receivers.NetWorkChangeReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Quando tento buildar, ocorre o seguinte erro:

```
08:20:43.742 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] 
08:20:43.743 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
08:20:43.744 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] 
08:20:43.744 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] * What went wrong:
08:20:43.744 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
08:20:43.744 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] > Conversion = '2'
08:20:43.744 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] 
08:20:43.744 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] * Exception is:
```

> 08:20:43.745 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]
>   org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task
>   ':app:processDebugManifest'. 08:20:43.745 [ERROR]
>   [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]   at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
>   08:20:43.745 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
>   08:20:43.745 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
>   08:20:43.746 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:64)
>   08:20:43.746 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
>   08:20:43.746 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:42)
>   08:20:43.746 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
>   08:20:43.746 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
>   08:20:43.746 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
>   08:20:43.746 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask.executeWithoutThrowingTaskFailure(AbstractTask.java:310)
>   08:20:43.747 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at
>   org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.executeTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
>   08:20:43.747 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at
>   org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:63)
>   08:20:43.747 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at
>   org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:51)
>   08:20:43.747 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at
>   org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:23)
>   08:20:43.747 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at
>   org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:88)
>   08:20:43.747 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at
>   org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:37)
>   08:20:43.747 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at
>   org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:62)
>   08:20:43.747 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at
>   org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$200(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
>   08:20:43.748 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at
>   org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$2.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:68)
>   08:20:43.748 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at
>   org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
>   08:20:43.748 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at
>   org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:62)
>   08:20:43.748 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at
>   org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:55)
>   08:20:43.748 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at
>   org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:149)
>   08:20:43.748 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at
>   org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:106)
>   08:20:43.748 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at
>   org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:86)
>   08:20:43.748 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at
>   org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:90)
>   08:20:43.749 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.BuildModelActionRunner.run(BuildModelActionRunner.java:54)
>   08:20:43.749 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at
>   org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
>   08:20:43.749 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at
>   org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:41)
>   08:20:43.749 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at
>   org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
>   08:20:43.749 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:49)
>   08:20:43.749 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
>   08:20:43.749 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>   08:20:43.749 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
>   08:20:43.750 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>   08:20:43.750 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
>   08:20:43.750 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>   08:20:43.750 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
>   08:20:43.750 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>   08:20:43.750 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
>   08:20:43.751 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
>   08:20:43.751 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at
>   org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38) 08:20:43.751 [ERROR]
>   [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]   at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
>   08:20:43.751 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>   08:20:43.751 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.DaemonHealthTracker.execute(DaemonHealthTracker.java:47)
>   08:20:43.751 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>   08:20:43.751 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:66)
>   08:20:43.752 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
>   08:20:43.752 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>   08:20:43.752 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:71)
>   08:20:43.752 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
>   08:20:43.752 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>   08:20:43.752 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.HintGCAfterBuild.execute(HintGCAfterBuild.java:41)
>   08:20:43.753 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>   08:20:43.753 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
>   08:20:43.753 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:246)
>   08:20:43.753 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at
>   org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
>   08:20:43.753 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at
>   org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
>   08:20:43.753 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Caused by:
>   java.util.UnknownFormatConversionException: Conversion = '2'

Alguém já passou por isto?

Comment: Poderia postar seu AndroidManifest?

Comment: Editei! Obrigado!

Comment: Talvez valha a pena rodar o build com a flag `-info`, dependendo do seu build variant fica algo como `./gradlew :app:assembleDebug -info`. Vai gerar um log bem grande, mas talvez ajude a encontrar a causa do problema.

Answer (score 0):

Fala Thiago,

Tenta trocar o seu:

> buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'

por

> buildToolsVersion '23.0.0'

Abraços.

Comment: Tentei, e aí ocorre o seguinte: **Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> Some file crunching failed, see logs for details**